# Getting data from a query using the result of another query, is this possible

Tags: sql, t-sql

[image]

Let's say we have a hypothetical dataset regarding widget production as above. The first column is the name of the producers of the widgers, the second column is how many widgets they produced, the third column is the what kind of software they are running they have and the last column is there state. (this is an absurd example I know)

Let's say what I want a few things, I want the quantity produced for a given producer AND the average quantity in their stat

So let's say I do this for producer "A", the output I would want would look like this:

[image]

Where basically the SQL query dynamically realizes that producer A is in California and then goes ahead and gets me the average from the state. Is that possible?

I have the first part below, as it's pretty straightforward

```
Select Producer, Quantity, Type, State
FROM DataSource
WHERE Producer = A
```

What I need is something like:

```
Select Producer, Quantity, State, *avg(FunctionStateofProducer(A))*, avg(FunctionSoftwareofProducer(A))* 
FROM DataSource
WHERE Producer = A
```

One idea I had was just to take the average of each state and then group by state and then software but when I tried:

```
 Select Producer, Quantity, State, avg(output) as stateoutput, avg(output) as softwareoutput
    FROM DataSource
    WHERE Producer = A
    GROUP BY State, Type
```

The output of the two average columns was identical, so it looks like only the first GROUP BY is taking effect.

Comment: Could you provide primary key columns? Without this information creating proper join isn't possible.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned you are using T-SQL, so you can use the magic of window functions:

```
SELECT  Producer, 
        Quantity, 
        Type, 
        State,
        AVG(Output) OVER (PARTITION BY State) AS AverageOutputForState,
        AVG(Output) OVER (PARTITION BY Type) AS AverageOutputForSoftware
FROM    DataSource
```

If you provide DDL and sample data as script, along with your full desired result, we can have something to test against.

HTH

Answer (score -1):

I understood, that you would like to add averages for each state and producer in two separate columns.

```
select ds.producer, ds.quantity, ds.type, ds.state,  
st.avg_q_st, pr.avg_q_pr  
from datasource ds  
left join (  
  select state, avg(quantity) as avg_q_st  
  from datasource group by state  
) st on ds.state = st.state  
left join (  
  select producer, avg(quantity) as avg_q_pr  
  from datasource group by producer   
) pr on ds.state = pr.state
```